# How can i interact directaly with data using UIB-Unified Interbase (http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=5)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

in my current application i can set dataset of datasource to table component (IBdac component from Devart.com)which enable me editing the data in the dbgrid directly .
uibdataset is read only which that is means it is not possible to edit any things except through update sql.
how can i achieve this properties with UIB components?
i'm using delphi xe, firebird2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familier with UIB, but did you try to use the TUIBQuery component? In my application I always use IBQuery to modify data. 
Actually I use:
`TIBQuery -> TDataSetProvider -> TClientDataSet -> TDataSource`

If you are using a `TDataSetProvider` you have to invoke `TClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates` to post the changes to underlying database.

Comment: TUibQuery will not appear as Dataset for TDataSetProvider, so that i can't used it as you mentioned. i can use UIBDataSet but it is readOnly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put a TUIBDatabase, TUIBTransaction then a TUIBDataSet and it should be connected to your TUIBDatabase and TUIBTransaction at the end put a TDataSource connected to the TUIBDatabase:
TUIBDatabase -> TUIBDatabase -> TDataSource

e.g

```
object UIBTransaction1: TUIBTransaction
  DataBase = UIBDataBase1
end
object UIBDataBase1: TUIBDataBase
  Params.Strings = (
    'sql_dialect=3'
    'lc_ctype=NONE'
    'user_name=SYSDBA'
    'password=masterkey'
    'sql_role_name=')
  DatabaseName = 
    'D:\FIREBIRDTEST.FDB'
  UserName = 'SYSDBA'
  PassWord = 'masterkey'
  LibraryName = 'fbclient.dll'
end
object UIBDataSet1: TUIBDataSet
  Transaction = UIBTransaction1
  Database = UIBDataBase1
  SQL.Strings = ('select * from CUSTOMER;')
end
object DataSource1: TDataSource
  DataSet = UIBDataSet1
end
```

you can also use the option mentioned by markus_ja however don't use TUIBQuery but use TUIBDatabase instead

TUIBDatabase -> TUIBDatabase -> TDataSetProvider -> TClientDataSet -> TDataSource

simply paste this code on your form:

```
object UIBTransaction1: TUIBTransaction
  DataBase = UIBDataBase1
  Left = 120
  Top = 112
end
object UIBDataBase1: TUIBDataBase
  Params.Strings = (
    'sql_dialect=3'
    'lc_ctype=NONE'
    'user_name=SYSDBA'
    'password=masterkey'
    'sql_role_name=')
  DatabaseName = 
    'D:\FIREBIRDTEST.FDB'
  UserName = 'SYSDBA'
  PassWord = 'masterkey'
  LibraryName = 'fbclient.dll'
end
object UIBDataSet1: TUIBDataSet
  Transaction = UIBTransaction1
  Database = UIBDataBase1
  SQL.Strings = ('select * from CUSTOMER;')
end
object DataSetProvider1: TDataSetProvider
  DataSet = UIBDataSet1
end
object ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet
  ProviderName = 'DataSetProvider1'
end
object DataSource1: TDataSource
  DataSet = ClientDataSet1
end
```

i hope that helps